# i have a php variable which is storing the substring of a string. but on the click of a button i want it to store the whole string

Tags: php

```
<?php
$short_description = 
substr($brand_description,0,299);//$short_description is  storing the substring
echo '<span>';
<p>About:</p> '.$short_description.'</span>'; 
echo '<span id="read_more">'; echo '<button onclick="display_more()"> Read more</button>'; echo '</span>';
?>
```

//onclick of the read more button i want $short_description to store the whole of $brand_description

Comment: welcome to SO, please have a quick look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: and [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: store the entire php variable in a javascript variable and display it when you click on the button

Answer (score 0):

try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/emLf0p2z/)

and in your js part do like this

```
$('#changeMe').text('<?php echo $brand_description;?>');
```